# Single column values into multiple columns in hive

Tags: hive

I have table which updates on weekly basis, I need to check count variation check between one week and previous week values. I just did below....

```
Select
case when F.wk_end_d=max(F.wk_end_d) over (partition by F.wk_end_d)then F.the_count end as count
from
(
    select wk_end_d, count(*) as the_count
    from table A
    where wk_end_d between date_sub('2019-03-02',7) and '2019-03-02'
    group by wk_end_d
) F
```

which give me value like below

```
100
200
```

but I need get value like `100 200` on 2 different columns as I need build some other calculations on top of it.

Comment: Team, any update on the above issue..??

Comment: You cannot add columns dynamically in Hive. There should be some hard-coded logic for each column

Comment: Okay, let me try, what I can hard code to get desired output. Thanks again. Will get back.

Comment: I got it, we just need to do a cross join as I need to compare only 2 wk_end_d dates...count
    (select wk_end_d, count(*) as the_count
    from table A
    where wk_end_d=Date_sub('2019-03-02',7) group by wk_end_d
) F join (
    select wk_end_d, count(*) as the_count
    from table A
    where wk_end_d= '2019-03-02'
    group by wk_end_d
) G